# Reading and printing file contents using Perl

Tags: perl

Can any body help me in reading all the files of particular format from the directory line by line and it should print on screen.

And my request is to include command lines in the program itself.

Then when ever simple I ran the program , it should display all the content of files.
Below is the program I wrote can any body help me please....

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
$filepath="/home/hclabv";
opendir(DIR,"$filepath");
@files=grep{/\.out$/} readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);
$c = 0;
for ($c=0 ;
while ($c <= @files)
{
$cmd = "Perlsc11 $files[$c]";
system($cmd);
if($#ARGV != 0) {
   print STDERR "You must specify exactly one argument.\n";
exit 4;
}
else
{
print ("$files[$c]\n");  
# Open the file.
open(INFILE, $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]: $!.\n";
while(my $l = <INFILE>) {
print $l;
}
close INFILE;
}
$c++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able understand what you want neither from your question neither form your code. Is it even valid Perl code?

Comment: How about `perl -pe0 ~/hclabv/*.out` ? Or simply `cat ~/hclabv/*.out`

Comment: Hi Hynek, what I want to do is .... I want to read and display all the contents of the files with extension .out on to the screen. And plese see the code i have given , where i have included command lines inside the program. And I can able to display all the content of the files by using above code ( But it is displaying infinite times ) I mean endles loop.. so please help me to sort out this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) feature in perl to get a list of filenames with the ".out" extension in the specified directory. You can then `open` these files one by one using a loop and print their contents to the screen. Here's the code,

```
# get all file-names with ".out" extension into array
my @outFiles = glob "/home/hclabv/*.out";

# loop through list of file names in array
foreach my $outFileName ( @outFiles )
{
    # open the file for processing
    open $outFile, '<', $outFileName or die "Unable to open file for reading : $!";

    # iterate through each line in the file
    while ( $line = <$outFile> )
    {
        # print the individual line
        print "$line\n";
    }

    # close the file
    close $outFile;
}
```

Please clarify what you mean by "including command lines", so we can help further.